# Corresponding 7zip command for unzip -p -a

Tags: terminal, tty, zip, stdout, 7z

I have a question regarding `unzip` command in Unix. As of now my Unix command `unzip -p -a` is able to zip the file which are lesser in size. But if the file size is larger then the command is not able to unzip it.

Consider the file name is `file1.zip` and when I give `unzip -p -a` and while the command executes, it shows the content of the file in the Unix box.
I want to know the same `7z` command.
@Volker:  you have suggested as `COMMANDTOUSE="/usr/bin/7z e -so -bd ..` but its not working.

This is how much code is defined,

if the file is in zip format, then the `unzip -p -a` comes into picture.
yes the command works for smaller files, and if fails for larger size.
I have tried with `7z e -so -bd` but its failing.
@Volker :  can you suggest an alternate command. Thanks for your continuous help till now.

Comment: Larger... than what?

Comment: larger is a comparative, i.e., you need to compare "935M" to something.

Comment: @ssice : please find the additional details above.

Comment: Can any of you guyz have a look and give me a update? its pretty much important

Comment: @chandraprakash So you mean a 935MB file is a large file example? (It could be the small file, in comparison: comparing to 2GB, see next.) There are various reports that some implementation of `zip` does not support files larger than 4GB, and sometimes larger than 2GB (maybe larger or equal). That would explain your problem, if the large file was larger than 2GB - but it's smaller. But I did not see any similar reports with files smaler than 2GB

Comment: Yes @VolkerSiegel your right. My zip command doesn't work if its larger than 4GB.Than what should be solution in that case? It would be great if I get a 7z command.

Comment: @chandraprakash But you tested it with 935MB, and it did not work, right? Then, it can not be that problem. (Got the same error you get with more than 4GB?) Or did you not test, but just guessed, and guessed wrong?

Comment: @VolkerSiegel : I am able to unzip for the files smaller than 4GB. I am facing problem for larger than 4GB..Pls have a look to http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165652/7z-command-for-files-larger-than-4gb-unzip-doesnt-work?noredirect=1#comment272108_165652

Comment: What did not work with more than 4GB - your `unzip`, or my `7z` solution? Please try to be more precise.

Answer (score 1):

The direct aequivalent of `unzip -p -a` for 7zip is `7z e -so -bd`. But that complains it does not want to write to stdout (even if I clearly told itso):

```
$ 7z e -so -bd file.zip 
7-Zip [64] 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,8 CPUs)

Error:
I won't write data and program's messages to same terminal
```

To make it not complain, you need to pipe or redirect the output of it somewhere else. For example, to read the output on the screen:

```
$ 7z e -so -bd file.zip | less
```

or to save it to a file:

```
$ 7z e -so -bd file.zip > file-all.txt
```

Comment: Hi Volker .. thanks for the answer..it was helpful.But we need to use this command in a program for data extraction which will be available in a particular path...so I just need to know the corresponding 7z command for COMMANDTOUSE="/usr/bin/unzip -p -a" which is coded. The command should allow for stdout.

Comment: @chandraprakash Yes, what's missing? `7z` should be in `/usr/bin/7z`

Comment: @Volker..Yup that available...but I need to know a command without pipeline or to save a file...is there any?

Comment: @chandraprakash Sure, as I wrote, `7z e -so -bd file.zip` - except that it does not work if you write to the terminal. I see, I did not make clear the the point with the terminal in the first section - is that the confusion?

Comment: @chandraprakash Let me know what your problem is - like the error message. What is wrong with `COMMANDTOUSE="/usr/bin/7z e -so -bd`?

Comment: @volker..I don't want to read or save it to the file...will the command COMMANDTOUSE="/usr/bin/7z e -so -bd will be executable.Because if I run  7z e -so -bd DEX_DWH.zip ..I get the below message                                                         7-Zip 9.20  Copyright (c) 1999-2010 Igor Pavlov  2010-11-18
p7zip Version 9.20 (locale=en_US.UTF-8,Utf16=on,HugeFiles=on,64 CPUs)
Error:
I won't write data and program's messages to same terminal.. so the command COMMANDTOUSE="/usr/bin/7z e -so -bd will be successful? as I need not pipe or redirect toa file

Comment: @chandraprakash It depends on how you will run it - can you describe? I can probably find a way around the problem, if I know it. So give me more details. That you can not just try in the shell, in terminal, it clear from the above. But normally, you would use it somehow else. Please edit your question to add new information, and the comment above. The comments may get lost, and it should be useful to others later.

Comment: @ Volker : I have changed my questions and added few details. Please find above.

Comment: @chandraprakash You say it works for smaller files, but not for larger? A file  like 500 characters text in one file packed in a zip file is a "small file" - right so far? Now, what's a larger file? One with 501 characters, with slightly increased zip file size is larger. But that seems to be a bad test case. I will propose a test file: The Linux kernel source of a specific release, as 146MB zip, as provided by git. That is a larger file, do you agree? And please explain exactly: in which way the command will be executed, and where the variable `COMMANDTOUSE` is used.

Comment: @chandraprakash Best would be if you can give the code of an independant demonstration of the problem. (For a large example file, use `wget -c 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux/archive/v3.17.zip'`)

Comment: :let me explain you in little detail. This are the two files which are in server                              -rwxr-xr-x  1 mule users   92731432 Oct 29 09:45 DEX_DWH034.zip and    -rwxr-xr-x  1 mule users  980200007 Oct 29 09:46 DEX_DWH.zip. If I run unzip -p -a for unzip -p -a DEX_DWH.zip .. it doesn't get executed as below   <mule@dayrhegmpp012:/tmp>$ unzip -p -a DEX_DWH.zip
<mule@dayrhegmpp012:/tmp>$                                      but if I run unzip -p -a DEX_DWH034.zip I can see the data present in my file in command prompt. So I need a corresponding 7z command.

Comment: what does the above link wget -c 'https://github.com/torvalds/linux/archive/v3.17.zip' will do if I run?

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not mention: `wget` will download that file. We will use the file only as our common example file. It is not relevant what is in it. It's a tradition to use the Linux kernel for this kind of example file.  It will download the source code of a specific version of the Linux kernel. So if we both use it, we can both do the same test.

Comment: And please edit the question for adding detail - not only because comments are unreadable with shell output/code.

Answer (score 0):

The corresponding 7zip command is `7zip x -so` that will extract your archive to the standard output stream.

Comment: @ linkoff : please find the additional details in the questions